# Why is my Backbone Collection not pulling in data?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm not getting any errors, but for some reason my data is not being loaded into my views. I'm using Requirejs and Marionette. I've been staring at this so long, it's probably right in front of me and I've just got tunnel vision and cant see it. Here are my files:

Here is my main.js:

```
    define([
        "jquery",
        "underscore",
        "backbone",
        "marionette",
        "app/views/Listings",
        "app/collections/ListingsCollection"], function($, _, Backbone, Marionette, Listings, ListingsCollection){

        "use strict";

        var App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

        App.addRegions({
            listingRegion: "#listingsView"
        });

        var listingsCollection = new ListingsCollection();
        listingsCollection.fetch().done(function () {
            var listingsView = new Listings({collection: listingsCollection});
            App.listingRegion.show(listingsView);    
        });

        App.start();
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
```

Here is my ListingsItemView.js

```
    define(['marionette', 'tpl!app/views/templates/Listings'],
        function (Marionette, template) {
        "use strict";

        var ListingsItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            template: template()
        });
        return ListingsItemView;
    });
```

Here is my ListingsCollectionView.js:
(note: this console.log under the initialize method will not show up in the console.)

```
define(['marionette', 'backbone', 'app/views/ListingsItemView'], function (Marionette, Backbone, ListingsItemView) {
    'user strict';

    var ListingsCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

        initialize: function() { 
            console.log('Collection view log: ' + this.collection); 
        },

        childView: ListingsItemView,
        tagName: 'ul'

    });

    return ListingsCollectionView;

});
```

Here is my template where the data is supposed to load:

```
<div>
    <h1>LISTINGS</h1>
    <ul>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my ListingsModel.js:

```
define(['marionette', 'backbone'], function (Marionette, Backbone) {
    'use strict';

    var ListingsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    });
    return ListingsModel;
});
```

And finally, here is my ListingsCollection.js:

```
define(['backbone', 'marionette', 'app/models/ListingsModel'], function (Backbone, Marionette, ListingsModel) {
    'user strict';

    var ListingsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ListingsModel,
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/post'
    });
    return ListingsCollection;
});
```

Note: I do not get any errors in the console when running this app. I just don't get any data loaded. The URL `http://localhost:1337/post` successfully sends this data through the Postman Chrome extension:

```
[
    {
        "userID": "54e6a5de61505403004698d8",
        "title": "Granite counter tops",
        "description": "I'm looking for granite counter tops for my kitchen. Willing to trade my skill set.",
        "email": "email@gmail.com",
        "createdAt": "2015-02-20T03:12:46.349Z",
        "updatedAt": "2015-02-20T03:12:46.349Z",
        "id": "54e6a62e61505403004698d9"
    },
    {
        "userID": "54e6b0236430c203000ecb86",
        "title": "Just a Yahoo looking for a lawn mower",
        "description": "need it now",
        "email": "email@yahoo.com",
        "createdAt": "2015-02-20T03:55:37.705Z",
        "updatedAt": "2015-02-20T03:55:37.705Z",
        "id": "54e6b0396430c203000ecb87"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2015-03-03T05:03:39.176Z",
        "updatedAt": "2015-03-03T05:03:39.176Z",
        "id": "54f540abdeddf07904a95cab"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2015-03-03T05:04:11.428Z",
        "updatedAt": "2015-03-03T05:04:11.428Z",
        "id": "54f540cbdeddf07904a95cac"
    },
    {
        "userID": "54e6a5d261505403004698d7",
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "email": "email@yahoo.com",
        "createdAt": "2015-03-03T16:08:06.843Z",
        "updatedAt": "2015-03-03T16:08:06.843Z",
        "id": "54f5dc660676aa030096bf30"
    },
    {
        "userID": "54e6a5d261505403004698d7",
        "title": "My title",
        "description": "Descrip",
        "email": "email@gmail.com",
        "createdAt": "2015-03-03T16:08:21.464Z",
        "updatedAt": "2015-03-03T16:08:21.465Z",
        "id": "54f5dc750676aa030096bf31"
    }
]
```

Comment: looks like problem is main.js - i think it would be better to move fetch logic to collection view and add  to initializer `this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this)`, as your main.js share controller responsibilities you may keep there only instancing views, models and hook it up. Also a good practice run initial actions on app start - so wrap code where you init models and view in `on('start')` callback. the final point is `tpl!` - does it return functions ? very often `text!` in use and it return template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main.js you defined "app/views/Listings" but according to your filenames it should be "app/views/ListingsCollectionView".